# React Native how to pass the value from component to the main activity without using Redux?

Tags: react-native

I am making a upload product for selling .
And I had make a component for receive the input number(units or price) from the user,
and in the main page will need to count the total price : units * price ..
However ,I get stucked here ... I don't know how I am able to get the value from the component ..

I have attached my code . Could you please take a look ? Thank you so much !!

**Component for putting number**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import colors from '../config/colors';

function TryInputNum({children}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Enter a number">{children}</TextInput>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container :{
        width : 150,
        height : 200,
        backgroundColor : colors.white,
    }
})
export default TryInputNum;
```

**The main page**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,Text } from 'react-native'
import TryInputNum from '../components/TryInputNum';
import colors from '../config/colors';

function TryCountScreen({children}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{children}</Text>
           <TryInputNum/> 
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex :1,
        backgroundColor : colors.primary,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
    }
})
export default TryCountScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass onChangeText function from the children and access it as a prop inside the main component. In the onChangeText you can return the text value from the TextInput component and handle it inside the main component. It would like like this

```
function TryInputNum({children,onChangeText}) {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput onChangeText={value => onChangeText(value)} placeholder="Enter a 
       number">{children}</TextInput>
    </View>
);
}
```

and then deal with the value from the main screen like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,Text } from 'react-native'
import TryInputNum from '../components/TryInputNum';
import colors from '../config/colors';

function TryCountScreen({children}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{children}</Text>
          //Here you have access to that text value thats written inside the
          // TextInput component
           <TryInputNum onChangeText={text => console.log(text)}/> 
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex :1,
        backgroundColor : colors.primary,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
    }
})
export default TryCountScreen;
```